# Intellij android project unable to launch with databinding enabled

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-databinding

I was following the android lessons on [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-data-binding-basics/index.html?index=..%2F..android-kotlin-fundamentals#5) and they were introducing `databinding`. According to the code, all i needed to do was to enable `databinding` within the `build.gradle` file as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.lesson4"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

However, the project fails to build into the emulator, and I am presented with the error code: `Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.JAXBException'.`

1. I also went further to amend the `XML` file of `activity_main` to wrap the `ConstraintLayout` within a `Layout` tag, but I think the error is somewhere within the gradle build portion instead.
2. I have tried various methods, such as `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` as well as including the kotlin dependencies, but the same error still persist.
3. I have also tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it.
4. I have also tried creating a brand new project, and only enabling `databinding`... The same error persists.

Hope someone can enlighten me about how to get databinding working in intellij for android?

Comment: try to build the project with Java JDK version 8. It seems that all versions above 8 in Android Studio generate some problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon some research I have found that data binding will throw errors while using Java 9+.

All you have to do is set your Java to version 8 and it should work.

**I don't want to use Java 8**

Then you have to manually add the JAX-B dependencies

```
kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
kapt "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
kapt "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:2.3.2"
annotationProcessor "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1" 
annotationProcessor "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"
```

And apply the kotlin-kapt plugin with:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: Hello, Thanks for your response. I have tried both methods actually. installing jdk8 and switching my project structure to run on that instead of `java11`. No luck there. I've also added `"apply plugin: kotlin-kapt"` and added those `3 items` into the dependencies. But still met with the same error.

Comment: Did you change your java references (to version 8) in build.gradle?

Comment: Yep, I just did, and it worked... on java 8.. lol. Thanks man. But its strange that even on Java11, I am not able to do it with the dependencies added...! Anyway, thank you very much for helping with this :)

Comment: im glad it worked, just one more thing - on Java 9+ if you're using Kotlin AND Java, try adding this to your dependencies    `annotationProcessor "com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-core:2.3.0.1"
    annotationProcessor "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1"`